# Create new column in mysql to convert unix time into readable date and time

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to create a new column in my table to convert a unix time column into human readable date and time.

I have found a few functions but am having trouble with the syntax as I do not normally use mysql. In this case it is required though.

Also, the unix time column I currently have is in milliseconds, could you please assist with this also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the unix time column in the same table ?
You can add a datetime column to the table, then run an update to translate the old records:

```
update foo_table set datetimecolumn=from_unixtime(unixcolumn);
```

Then you can add a trigger to the table to auto translate every time an insert is performed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `toDateTime` BEFORE INSERT ON `foo_table` FOR EACH ROW  set new.datetimecolumn=from_unixtime(new.unixcolumn);
```

UPDATE:

as it is in milliseconds, you can use this

```
from_unixtime(CAST(unixcolumn/1000 as BIGINT))
```